# Stash: is it possible to prevent direct pushes to repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

We are using Atlassian Stash Git repository. We want all the team members to be able to approve pull requests to repository or some branches, but we want only several members or no one to be able to commit to repository without pull request.

Also we would like to prevent the situation when same person that has made a commit approves the pull request.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you can do it by using hooks.
Go to your setting section, hooks and search for the suitable hook for you, install it form the market (or write your own hook if you know how to) and set the required permissions.

#### How to do it?

1. Add code to the `pre-recieve` hook which block everybody beside the users in your whitelist.
2. Install `async hooks` form atlasian market place (Settings>Add-ons) and follow the instructions if you need some extra configuration - like writing your own script.